# TSQL - ROUND price to .05 and .09. UPDATE is producing NULLs?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table, PriceTable,

columns UPC (int), Price (money)

I am trying to round all of the cents in the Price column, to end in either .x5 or .x9.

If the last digit of the price is 0-5, then the last digit should be a 5.
If the last digit of the price is 6-9, then the last digit should be a 9. 

Examples

- 1.00 goes to 1.05
- 1.21 goes to 1.25
- 1.26 goes to 1.29

I am using the following, but after the update, I am getting some records where the price is being updated to NULL and I can't figure out why. It is working correctly for 95% of the data, but I can't see anything different with the data where it isn't.

My thinking was the (Round(Price,1,2) gives me the dollar in the Price. Subtract that from the overall Price to get the cents and then use the CASE statement add the correct .05 or .09 back to the Price.

```
UPDATE PriceTable
SET Price = ROUND(Price,1,2) + 
CASE 
WHEN Price -(ROUND(Price,1,2)) BETWEEN .00 AND .05 THEN .05
WHEN Price -(ROUND(Price,1,2)) BETWEEN .06 AND .09 THEN .09
END;
```

Is there a better way to do this? I can't wrap my head around why I would get a NULL for Price when all cent scenarios should be accounted for and even if they weren't, I should still get the dollar amount of price with the ROUND(Price,1,2). I shouldn't need an ELSE as there shouldn't be any other conditions.

Thanks,

Marshall

Comment: There must be prices like 1.255 or 1.295 which fall through the cracks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get NULL values for all prices where the value ends with a value that is 0.05 < ThatValue < 0.06. Change it to an else, and 0.050018 will get rounded to 0.06, instead of NULL.

```
UPDATE PriceTable
SET Price = ROUND(Price,1,2) + 
CASE 
WHEN Price -(ROUND(Price,1,2)) BETWEEN .00 AND .05 THEN .05
ELSE .09
END;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. The values in between .05 and .06 were the problem ones. Thanks for the help and quick response.